# There cannot be more than three primes of the form $n^{n^2}-k$ for the same $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I was searching for primes of the form $n^{n^2}-k$ on PARI/GP and noticed that primes of this form for same $k$ are quite rare. The probability of finding a prime of this form is $\frac {1}{n^2 \log (n)}$, which makes me believe that the number of primes for same $k$ of this form would be finite.

I also noticed that the maximum number of primes of the form $n^{n^2}-k$ for the same $k$ seems to be three.

I searched for a range of $k \le 3 \times 10^5$ and $n \le 50$ on PARI/GP and didn't find more than three primes for same $k$. Here are the some values of $k$, for $k \le 10^4$ I found on PARI/GP, that have three primes of the form $n^{n^2}-k$. The first column displays the values of $k$ and the second column shows the values of $n$ for which $n^{n^2}-k$ is prime.

```
1409 [4, 6, 8]
3083 [4, 6, 8]
5496 [5, 7, 13]
7427 [4, 6, 8]
8902 [3, 9, 15]
```

**Questions:**

> $(1)$ Can there not be more than three primes of the form $n^{n^2}-k$ for the same $k$?
>
> $(2)$ If there can be more than three, then is there a maximum number of primes of the form $n^{n^2}-k$ for the same $k$?

Edit 1: Following the same process, I believe that the maximum number of primes of the form $n^{n^2}+k$, for same $k$ is four.

Edit 2: Peter showed provided an example with four primes for the same $k$ which solves my question $1$. So now I only look for answers of question 2.

Comment: Mod 5 destroys a lot.

Comment: if n is even $k\equiv 1 \bmod p$ forces n congruent to 0 mod p, if n is odd k is congruent to n mod p. These additive inverse on the second form. at least in a few cases.

Comment: If $k$ is odd and $n$ is even, then $k$ might be prime itself, so none of $n$ divides $k$.

Comment: I think, $5$ solutions for the same $k$ is challenging, but the bunyakovsky conjecture could imply that arbitary many solutions are possible (at least in the +k-version), but I have to work it out first.

Comment: mod 3 Actually eliminates more than 55% and non overlapping with mod 5 would yeild about 8.4% of cases surviving mod 15.

Answer (score 3):

For $$k=1996199$$ the numbers $$4^{4^2}-k$$ $$6^{6^2}-k$$ $$8^{8^2}-k$$ $$10^{10^2}-k$$ are all prime

Comment: All except n=10, get destroyed on the +k side as k is -1 mod 5. n=10 gets destroyed by mod 3 for the plus side.

Comment: Nice work Peter! Though I do believe that that a maximum number of primes for same $k$ does exist (could be 5 till now).

Comment: if not for overlap you'd only have 19 scenarios left mod 15 @Mathphile

Comment: $k=33213007$ gives (at least) $5$ solutions in the "+"-version

Comment: $k=247342073$ gives (at least) $5$ solutions in the "-" -version

Comment: Those numbers were found by Enzo Creti